Sourcetree stuck when clone repository
I try first cloning via sourcetree (version 3.4.18), and it stuck at:

The Source tree is stuck at 100% for: Updating files: 100%
(7891/7891), done.

When I do cloning in command line, I do that with no problem.
I generally do:
git clone <my http repo link>

For the source tree - it is too long clone command (I don't know why).
git -c filter.lfs.smudge= -c filter.lfs.required=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks clone --branch master <my http repo link> <my folder>

When I run in command line as same command as same sourcetree provided, it is not stuck.
I have tried changing some configurations of the sourcetree
(such as check some of the options for git in sourcetree, or trying to check correct authentication for the account - when the authentication is created, I can choose only https, but the repsitory address starts with http),
to check whether it solve the problem - it didn't.
What can I check in order solving the problem?
Thanks.
